# Find & replace in visual studio not replacing all occurrences

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am using ctrl+shift+f to trigger "Find and replace", going to the tab "Replace in files".

I do a regexp search in the entire solution (which contains around 11000 files) for:

```
#layout(\d+)-top
```

replacing that with

```
#layout$1 .layout-top
```

A lot of files are changed by the operation, but when I after the operation open a certain css file, I still can read lines like:

```
#layout5-top,
#layout6-top
{
    width: 960px;
    height: 104px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Why?

If I do the same search & replace with that file open, the operation will affect the file.

I can find numerous files that are not changed by the way.

In the progress indicator that comes up when the search and replace runs, I see that every file is processed, not just open files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I hit exactly the same problem. It only seems to happen when using a regular expression. I know that the files are being matched because if I swap to just 'find in files', the correct lines are matched in the files. It seems to be a bug to me. Possibly, Microsoft don't trust us not to shoot ourselves in the foot with regexes. ;)

The only way I could resolve it was to select the option:

> Replace All will open all files with changes for editing

[image]

If you don't get this warning dialog, you may have disabled it, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165349%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Then just type <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to save all files and close all.
This seemed to work when there were around 200 files with replacements (the full set of files searched was around 10000). I am not sure how many files Visual Studio can have open at one time, so I imagine at some point it will no longer work or replacements will be missed, in which case you may need to run it a number of times.